# lwc not supported on app page (mobile)

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, mobile

I have a lwc that I want to be displayed on app mobile but it's giving me always the following error:

[image]

This is my lwc .XML configuration:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
            <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
        </targetConfig>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="recordpage_display" type="Boolean" default="true"></property>
            <supportedFormFactors>
                <supportedFormFactor type="Large"/>
            </supportedFormFactors>
        </targetConfig>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__AppPage">
            <property name="recordpage_display" type="Boolean" default="true"></property>
            <supportedFormFactors>
                <supportedFormFactor type="Small" />
            </supportedFormFactors>
        </targetConfig>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__HomePage">
            <supportedFormFactors>
                <supportedFormFactor type="Large" />
            </supportedFormFactors>
        </targetConfig>
   </targetConfigs>
    </LightningComponentBundle>
```

Is there something I'm setting wrong or missing in order to make it work properly?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to support mobile on record page you just have to add `<supportedFormFactor type="Small" />` to the related supportedFormFactors section:

```xml
<targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
    <property name="recordpage_display" type="Boolean" default="true"></property>
    <supportedFormFactors>
        <supportedFormFactor type="Large"/>
        <supportedFormFactor type="Small" />
    </supportedFormFactors>
</targetConfig>
```

Please note that Home pages support only the Large form factor, [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_config_form_factors).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now!